# Reading selected values from a file and writing them in a new file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I wanted to take user input(integer value) from keyboard and writing them in a file.Then, to select the values from 18-80 and writing in another file.My program runs till keyboard input and writing them in a file. But I don't know how to select some values under condition and writing them in another file.

```
  #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

   ofstream age;
   age.open("age.txt",ios::out);  
   cout<<"Input the ages from keyboard: "<<endl;

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
       int n;
       cin>>n;        //value inputted from keyboard
       age<<n<<endl;
   }

   ifstream agein;
   agein.open("age.txt");   //Reading that existing file

   ofstream ageout;
   ageout.open("information.txt");   //writing in another file
   {
       int m;
       if(m>18 && m<=80)      //picking value from 18-80
       ageout<<m<<endl;
   }

       age.close();
       agein.close();
       ageout.close();
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while( std::getline() )`?

Comment: Off topic: You will need to close `age` before opening the file again for reading.

Comment: Why are you making a condition using `m` without putting anything in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to close your file before reopening it, even if you switch from read/write.
Here you go:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream age;
    age.open("age.txt", ios::out);
    cout << "Input the ages from keyboard: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;        //value inputted from keyboard
        age << n << endl;
    }

    age.close();// Do NOT forget that before reopening it

    ifstream agein;
    agein.open("age.txt");   //Reading that existing file

    ofstream ageout;
    ageout.open("information.txt");//writing in another file
    if(ageout)//Checks if the file exists
    {
        string str;
        int m;
        while (agein >> m) //Get an int from a file
            if (m>18 && m <= 80)      //picking value from 18-80
                ageout << m << endl;
    }
    agein.close();
    ageout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but not a good question not answer in full like this. It is too cut-n-pastable for something that wears the scent of homework. I'd restrict the answer to the contents of `if(ageout)` and possibly reduce it to pseudocode. Point them in the right direction, but make OP think and research a bit.

Comment: I actually only gave a complete answer for anyone that will find this question helpful since this is a really common problem for begginners, i don't really care about the OP here

Comment: Dangerous answer, friend. Care Bears could be listening.

Comment: It was not my home work.It was just a little part of a problem.Actually I am just a newbie who don't know the basic syntax yet now.Thank you all by the way.